# Create MS access database file, table and field using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to create a database file using VB.net coding, database file name "College1". in database file 'College1' I want to add a table with name "StudentList". in Table 'StudentList' i want to add following fields
1. Student Name
2. DOB
3. Course
4. Mobile No.
and If possible can I format columns as well eg.DOB as date format and Mobile No. as number format

Comment: So what is the question? What have you tried? What failed - and what was the exception. Please provide code you've tried so far.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c26a043e-e6d8-4907-88db-39b8262c92f6/create-access-db-using-c-and-import-few-tables-using-code?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I want whole code of my queries.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317867/how-to-create-a-microsoft-access-database-by-using-adox-and-visual-bas

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to create an MS Access database using VB.NET.

```
Imports ADOX
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cat As Catalog = New Catalog()
        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &
                    "Data Source=C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\NewMDB.mdb;" &
                    "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")
        Console.WriteLine("Database Created Successfully")
        cat = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note: you need to add a reference to `'Microsoft ADO Ext 2.8'`

And, here is a generic example of how to write data to MS Access from a TextBox in VB.NET.  I think you want to do a bit more than just create the database, right...

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1



    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ' Requires: Imports System.Data.OleDb

        ' ensures the connection is closed and disposed
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=""C:\your_path_here\InsertInto.mdb"";" & _
            "Persist Security Info=False")
            ' open connection
            connection.Open()

            ' Create command
            Dim insertCommand As New OleDbCommand( _
                "INSERT INTO Table1([inputOne] , [inputTwo] , [inputThree]) " & _
                "VALUES (@inputOne, @inputTwo, @inputThree);", _
                connection)
            ' Add the parameters with value
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputOne", TextBox1.Text)
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputTwo", TextBox2.Text)
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputThree", TextBox3.Text)
            ' you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection
            ' execute the command
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Insert is done!!")

        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to create a ms access db file.

```
Dim connectionString As String = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb;"
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
con.Open()
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE zzzTest (ID COUNTER, VALUES INTEGER)"
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Console.WriteLine("Table created.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Using
con.Close()
```

End Using

Use below links to create database and table as well.

[Create database and table](https://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_database/microsoftaccess/article.php/c5149/Create-a-Microsoft-Access-Database-Using-ADOX-and-Visual-Basic-NET.htm)

Comment: The code above doesn't create Database, it creates table only.